# Converting list of lists with tuple into data frame?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, data-conversion

I have the following nested lists:

```
 lst = [[1, 1, 10], 
        [1, 2, 28.6], 
        [1, 3, 26.93], 
        [1, 4, 20],
        [2, 1, 6],
        [2, 2, 4],
        [2, 3, 6],
        [2, 4, 23],
        [3, 1, 12], 
        [3, 2, 23], 
        [3, 3, 13],
        [3, 4, 43]]
```

The first and second items point to x and y, respectively, and the third item is the value of that particular cell. So I need to convert this lists into a data frame in which the first items should be the columns and the second items should be the index, and finally  the third items should be the value of that columns. Given the above example, my desired outcome should look like this:

```
mydata_frame:
              1       2     3    
           1  10      6     12
           2  28.6    4     23
           3  26.93   6     13
           4  20      23    43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df = df.pivot_table(2, 1, 0)
df.columns = sorted(set(list(zip(*lst))[0]))
df.index.name = None
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - first create a dataframe with multi-level columns from the `lst` and then use `.stack` to shape it into final form:

```py
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({(x, y): z for x, y, z in lst}, index=[0])
    .stack(level=1)
    .droplevel(0)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       1   2   3
1  10.00   6  12
2  28.60   4  23
3  26.93   6  13
4  20.00  23  43
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` and `rename_axis`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst).pivot(index=1, columns=0, values=2)
df = df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       1     2     3
1  10.00   6.0  12.0
2  28.60   4.0  23.0
3  26.93   6.0  13.0
4  20.00  23.0  43.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(lst).set_index(1).pivot(columns=[0], values=[2])
       2            
0      1     2     3
1                   
1  10.00   6.0  12.0
2  28.60   4.0  23.0
3  26.93   6.0  13.0
4  20.00  23.0  43.0
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).